# PHP Error Handling and to insert error details in a table?

Tags: php, sql, error-handling

I need to insert the error details for which the status is failed with id, transactionId, error details, Timestamp.

```
if (($record=$ctc->Transaction($transaction))===false) {
    $sql ="insert into $schema.error_table  ";
    $sql.="values(".$project.",".$transaction.",".$error_details", SYSDATE)";
    if(!$conn->Execute($sql)){
    displayErrorPage(&$page, "Error inserting record into odin error transaction table");
    $conn->CompleteTrans(false);
    exit();
}
```

But I could not insert the failed error details into the table. could anyone help me?

Comment: You will need a space between the table name and the work `values`, also any string fields should be in quotes (single in this case) or even better to use prepared statements.

Comment: Your SQL is `insert into something.tablevalues(thing, 12345, error details here, SYSDATE)` - this is just blatantly wrong...

Comment: sorry there is a space between table name and values.did mistake while editing here.

Comment: Please help me on this ?